# Set values after creating a JSON object Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am having some trouble setting some values for a widget I am making. I am using Ozone widget framework, but that part is negligible to this discussion. Here us the html where I am trying to set the variable (for now just focus on `{{user.user}}` part.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <p>User: {{user.user}}</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in records | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.model}}</td>
            <td>{{item.score}}</td>
            <td>{{item.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is the Angular / owf to go with it:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['cgOwf'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, owf) {
    var records;
    $scope.selectPost = '';
    $scope.searchText = ''; 
    console.debug("before IT HERE!!!");
   owf.ready(function(){
       console.debug("MADE IT HERE!!!");
      owf.Eventing.subscribe('user-status', function(sender, msg, channel) {
          console.debug('[%s] - received message %o', channel, msg);
          $scope.user = msg;
      });
   });

    $scope.search = function() {
      //clear the select, go here http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments
      //and display/filter emails based on the search input
      $scope.selectPost = "";
      $scope.selectedItem = null;
      $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1jvst').success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
          if (r && r.user && r.user.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
          }
        });
      });
    };

  });
```

The part I am having trouble with is `$scope.user = msg;`. At that point in the code, `msg` is a JSON object, and I am sure of that because it checks out in the js debugger in chrome. AFAIK that is how I would set the object so I could access it in the html, though something clearly doesn't work.

Comment: Is that `owf` event triggering a `$digest` cycle? Try `$scope.$apply()` after setting the value.;

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help

Comment: Is your controller associated to the view ok? Do you get anything if you just do {{user}} ?

Comment: @tymeJV I think that may have actually been the solution. The cache on chrome just sux so since I didn't clear it the old info was there.

Comment: @erp -- Gotta love cache issues... In chrome, you can set the cache to clear as long as the consoles open, as well as, if the consoles open you can right click the refresh button -> empty cache and hard reload.

Comment: @tymeJV well hey, if you want to make an answer to this question with what you said in the comment I'd have no problem giving it the vote.

Comment: @erp  -- Will do, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `owf` event probably isn't triggering a `$digest` cycle, so the view never updates. You can run `$scope.apply()` to force a `$digest`

```
owf.Eventing.subscribe('user-status', function(sender, msg, channel) {
      console.debug('[%s] - received message %o', channel, msg);
      $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.user = msg;
      });
});
```